# SharePoint 2010 set a custom page as home page through a feature

Tags: development, client-object-model

I have a WebTemplate using a team site as BaseTemplate,
and was wondring how I could set the default page as home page instead of the home.aspx page and this during the provisioning process of the site so through a feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, to set the home page for a given site in a feature receiver should be something like:

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

if( web != null ) 
{
SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder; 
rootFolder.WelcomePage = "UrlToMyPage.aspx";
rootFolder.Update();
}
```

Use that in FeatureActivated to set the home page in a feature.